# Ubuntu 12.04 Gitosis no longer available

Tags: 12.04, git, gitosis

I have an Ubuntu 11.10 box running git server using gitosis, installed as described here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git

I just tried upgrading to 12.04 doing a `do-release-upgrade`, and the gitosis package was removed and is no longer available in `apt-get`. This is the first time this happens to me, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Luckily, the box is virtualized, and I reverted to the backup, so no harm was done. But still, I want to upgrade and keep gitosis installed. What's the recommended way to proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gitosis is no longer actively maintained. You should migrate to [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/). There's a pretty detailed [migration guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20120504213216/http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/gsmigr.html) available.

Comment: Thank you, just migrated to gitolite, will upgrade the server later.

Answer (score 0):

On [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/gitosis) page you can the packages for your system. Select your system and download the .deb file which can be installed via the software centre.

Comment: What does it mean the "Status: Deleted" in launchpad?