# Easy to use Git server management

Tags: server, software-recommendation, git

Regarding source controls I have experience with TFS (Team Foundation Server) and I'm working with GitHub for some of my open source projects. Now I want to setup an authenticated Git server on my own server.

I've read some guides but they seem a bit complicated to me, specially when I have to deal with authentication. I'm looking for a simple and easy to setup/manage solution for that.

For example a web package that allows me to manage users and projects on a Git server. Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try out [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/).

However, as far as I know, there has not been a packaged version for Ubuntu, so you'd have to carry out the installation manually, and installation may be a little intrusive (it may litter files that are not tracked by the package manager over your system). Once it's up, management is pretty much a breeze though.

To get around the "intrusive" issue, you might want to consider installing it in a VM or a Linux Container (LXC) that runs only GitLab (like an application server).

Answer (score 0):

[Gitosis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/gitosis) is good Git authentication/user management software. Ive used it professionally in the past and found it easy to use and maintain. It wouldnt be difficult to set up a web based UI to manage it, as something like Gitlab is to Gitolite. See the "See also" section at the bottom of the page I've linked.

Comment: Is it true that [Gitosis is no longer actively maintained](http://askubuntu.com/a/126112/190988)?

Comment: This may be the case, I havent used Gitosis in a few years. This package was updated in 2013: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=23419. The last commit on the github page was 2009 :(.